# 'function' : no suitable method found to override c# key event

Tags: c#, winforms

It is possible to move this code into a **class** not a **form class** because it's very long and take a lot of space ? I want something like this : `On KeyPress => Class.ProcessCmdKey(...);` and i keep getting this error: **'function' : no suitable method found to override**

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if(keyData == Keys.A)
        {

        }
        if (keyData == Keys.B)
        {

        }
        if (keyData == Keys.C)
        {

        }
        if (keyData == Keys.D)
        {

        }
        if (keyData == Keys.E)
        {

        }
        if (keyData == Keys.F)
        {

        }
        G..H......
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Because it's long -> Then just use a [partial class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#partial-classes).

Comment: So, you moved your ProcessCmdKey method into another class. Did you already forget that you declared your method with the keyword `override`? (No need to trust my word. Just spend the ten seconds it takes for looking at your own source code there in your question.) So, let me ask you this question then: What method in that other class is your ProcessCmdKey method supposed to override?

Comment: Make partial class and make sure it is in the same namespace as form.

Comment: Just put it in a region and collapse it. No specific need for even partial classes, never mind an additional class.